# What practical uses are there for the AD feature of "Confidential Attributes"

Tags: appsec, access-control, confidentiality, active-directory, ldap

Are any applications (off the shelf, or internal) leveraging Active Directory's [Confidential Attributes](https://serverfault.com/q/181669/51457)?

Would you store sensitive information here such as a private key, or a salt here?

I'm planning a demonstration of this feature, but would like to cite as many real world usages, or implementations as possible.

Comment: I'm curious as well... most people don't even know about this attribute. Do you have a particular application for this, or are you just wanting to give a cool demo?

Comment: @SteveS The linked question references an application I'm independently building for sale.  People want to know where the seed is stored/calculated so I want to show that other applications use this as well and also that I'm not being "creative" with security

Answer (score 2):

I see that Stanford is using it as part of their bitlocker system recovery process [Stanford link](http://windows.stanford.edu/Public/Infrastructure/Services/BitLocker.html)

> For computers that are part of the Stanford Windows Infrastructure, a copy of the recovery password is stored with the computer object as a confidential attribute. By default, only Domain Administrators can see confidential attributes, no matter what access is granted by standard ACLs.

Looks like a great feature to leverage for Role Based Access Control but I don't have any examples at hand.